# Renaming column in R problems

Tags: r

I read csv file with fread. After that I rename one of column (the new name is My Id)  using setnames() and I write.csv file. I open again with fread and everything is ok. But when I try to open with read.csv and type names() the column names appear to be My.Id 
Should I consider to include read.csv not to check logical variables names.
How I can remove the dot between the column headings?

Comment: You can prevent R from checking for syntactically valid variable names by adding `check.names = FALSE` to `read.csv`.

Answer (score 0):

Column names are supposed to be valid R variable names.  Try ?make.names to get some more information.

The reasoning is simple.  Imagine trying to access that column.  The normal syntax is df$colName.  How would I do that easily with col Name?  You might want them as different names when outputting them, but during use in R, you probably don't.